# Building F# on a mac... mcs: No such file or directory

Tags: macos

I am building F# from source on my mac (yosemite).

I followed these steps.

```
git clone https://github.com/mono/mono

cd mono

./autogen.sh --prefix=/mono64 --enable-nls=no

make
```

During make I get an error

```
cd /Users/abhishek.srivastava/mono/mcs && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make --no-print-directory -s NO_DIR_CHECK=1 PROFILES='binary_reference_assemblies net_4_x xbuild_12 xbuild_14     ' CC='gcc' all-profiles
mkdir -p -- build/deps
make[6]: mcs: No such file or directory
make[6]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe] Error 1
*** The compiler 'mcs' doesn't appear to be usable.
*** You need Mono version 3.8 or better installed to build MCS
*** Check mono README for information on how to bootstrap a Mono installation.
/bin/sh: mcs: command not found
*** The version of 'mcs' is: .
make[5]: *** [do-profile-check] Error 1
make[4]: *** [profile-do--basic--all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [profiles-do--all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
LBURMAC603TG8WM:mono (master *=)$
```

Comment: Do `make get-monolite-latest` after `autogen.sh` and before making the rest.

Comment: Removing F# tags as this is just a question on compiling mono.

Comment: Your suggestion of `make get-monolite-latest` solved my problem. Can you please put it in as an answer so that i can mark it as an answer. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `make get-monolite-latest` after `autogen.sh` and before making the rest.

Alternatively, any recent [binary mono release](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) can be installed and used for bootstrapping.